# coldfusion hosting

Tags: coldfusion

Wondering if anyone can recommend a coldfusion shared hosting company that doesn't have all kinds of restrictions on java object creation, cfexecute scripts etc.  I know there are valid security reasons for not permitting these scripts, but before I go out and either rewrite my code or buy my own server, I owe it to myself to check first.

Comment: it probably depends on your budget - you'll probably get lots of VPS recommendations.

Comment: what you are basically asking is if there is a host with no security who do not care if their servers get hacked. You are not going to find any decent cf host allowing cfexecute, the only host who would have this enabled is one who is clueless about CF and security. Do you really want to be hosted in an environment where anyone could hack or delete your website or the entire server at any time ?
If you want the freedom to do as you like securely then you need your own VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a VPS.  I use Hosting.com.  I am quite happy with the service level, and the performance is way beyond shared hosting.  (I pay $179 monthly, but I resell enough sites to pay for it.)

You should be prepared to spend more, but if you can get a few friends together you will be happy you got away from shared hosting.  It is very liberating.